# PHP Download script (Locally)

Tags: php, odata

Im looking for a script that will take OData feed and download some .wmv files based on the filenames held within the OData?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you please clarify what "OData" is, what you mean by "locally", and what PHP has to do with it?

Comment: OData Protocol: http://www.odata.org
<br />
Example of OData: http://api.visitmix.com/OData.svc/

Locally - Rather than running this script on a remote server I want to run the script locally and download the files locally.

PHP - Recurse through the OData and download each resulting .wmv files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't be any different doing it locally than doing it on a remote server.

Step 1 - Parse the feed and pull out the links. Using something like SimplePie might be easy for you.

Step 2 - Download the links and save them where you need to save them. There is a snip of code  here:
http://www.finalwebsites.com/forums/topic/php-file-download

that shows how to perform the download.

Answer (score 1):

An OData feed is just an Atom feed.  So look for some PHP code that can process Atom feeds.  The only problem is that some of the OData feeds that are on the web at the moment do not validate.  Take for example the http://api.visitmix.com/OData.svc/Files endpoint.  It is missing a summary element so the atom parsing code may choke on that.  However, it's all xml anyway so parsing the file paths out of it is pretty trivial.

I could whip you up some C# code in a few mins to do this, but PHP is not going to happen :-)

Ok, so it took a bit longer than a few minutes, but [here](http://www.bizcoder.com/index.php/2010/03/20/using-the-httpclient-and-the-odata-service-to-download-mix-videos/) is the C# code to do it.